# Boxplot with multiple variables in multiple dataset with the same group in r

Tags: r, grouping, boxplot

I have 2 variables in 2 different datasets organized in the same sequences

df1:

```
LoopGW    NPV         Model
1          200         1
2          300         1
```

df2:

```
LoopGW    NPVadjusted        Model
1            300              3
2            400              3
```

I've tried this:

```
boxplot(NPV ~ loopGW, data = df1)
boxplot(NPVadjusted ~ loopGW, data= df2, add = TRUE)
```

But what I got is the boxplot with overlap.

[image]

I want all four boxplots separated and colored by model. Could anyone please help? Thanks so much

Comment: Bind rows of two dataframes and then do one boxplot call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really provided a reproducible example, so i just worked with what I had.
Hope it does what you want. There might be better ways to get there but this is what I did:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

#read the data
df1 <- read.table(text = "
LoopGW    NPV         Model
1          200         1
2          300         1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "
LoopGW    NPVadjusted        Model
1            300              3 
2            400              3", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)

#preparing the data.frames for binding so no information gets lost.
d1g <- gather(df1, key = "NPV_flag", value = "NPV", -Model, -LoopGW)
d2g <- gather(df2, key = "NPV_flag", value = "NPVadjusted", -Model, -LoopGW)

#binding the two data.frames
d12g <- rbind(d1g, setNames(d2g, names(d1g)))

#create the groups after which to seperate
d12g$Model_Loop <- paste(d12g$Model, "_", d12g$LoopGW, sep = "")

#Model as factor
d12g$Model <- as.factor(d12g$Model)

#Plot with ggplot
ggplot(d12g, aes(x = Model, y = NPV, group = Model_Loop, color = Model)) + geom_boxplot()
```

And that's the result. You have to imagine 4 nice boxplots there. ^^

[image]

I hope thats what you want. 4 Boxplots seperated by Loop and Model? And Colored by Model.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm trying your codes but I got the error of objective NPV not found. Hmmm

Comment: When I did ggplot.

Comment: Did it say "objective NPV not found" or "object NPV not found"? It seems like it doesn't find the column `NPV` in the data.frame. Can you check whether it is there? Maybe even post str(d12g) in your question?

Comment: Do you want to accept the answer? So others with the same problem know what worked for you. If the question did indeed solve your problem.

Comment: Sure. How do I do that?

Comment: Here you'll find the answer :-)
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work